# React virtualized infiniteLoader scrolling to top on load using List

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am currently using react-virtualized InfiniteLoader component to scroll over a List of elements that could be variable all the time.
This is my component now:

```
 <VirtualizedInfiniteLoader isRowLoaded={isRowLoaded} loadMoreRows={loadMoreRows} rowCount={rowCount}>
      {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ width, height }) => (
            <List
              key={`${width}${height}${rowCount}`}
              height={height - headerHeight}
              onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
              scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
              scrollToAlignment={scrollToAlignment}
              ref={registerChild}
              rowCount={rowCount}
              rowHeight={rowHeight}
              rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
              width={width}
              onScroll={onListScroll}
            />
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      )}
    </VirtualizedInfiniteLoader>
```

And i'm using this in a container:

```
 renderInfiniteLoader = currentStatus => {
    const { cache, headerHeight } = this.state;
    const { scrollToIndex, params, allTasks, selectedFilterFields, searchFilters } = this.props;
    const list = allTasks[currentStatus];

    console.log(list.length, params);

    return (
      <InfiniteLoaderWrapper
        diffHeight={marginBottomToAdd({ searchFilters, selectedFilterFields, customerID: params.customerID })}
        ref={this.cardsContainer}
      >
        <InfiniteLoader
          loadMoreRows={options => this.loadMoreRows(options, status)}
          rowRenderer={this.renderTasks(list, currentStatus)}
          isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded(list)}
          scrollToIndex={scrollToIndex}
          scrollToAlignment="start"
          rowCount={list.length + 1}
          headerHeight={150}
          deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
          rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
          onListScroll={this.onInfiniteLoaderScroll}
        />
      </InfiniteLoaderWrapper>
    );
  };
```

The problem here is that everytime i scroll down and a loader appear if i'm scrolling too fast, page scroll to first element on top.
The prop `scrollToIndex` seems to be 0 everytime so probably that's the problem.
If i remove that prop, scrolling works correctly, but comes up another issue:
I can click on list's element to go to a detail page, and if i come back i expect to be in the correct position of the list, but i'm on top (again, because scrollToIndex is 0).

What is the correct value to pass to scrollToIndex to be always in the right point?

I can see there was this bug in some version of react-virtualized but can't find any workaround.

Thanks in advance!